# Remove everything after second colon

Tags: regex, text, notepad++

I need to remove everything after the colon following orange

Example:

```
apple:orange:banana:grapes:
```

Becomes:

```
apple:orange
```

I've looked up a million different references for this and cannot find a solution.

Currently doing this in Notepad++ using the Find/Replace function.

Answer (score 2):

**Find what** : `(^[a-z]+:[a-z]+).*$`

- `(^[a-z]+:[a-z]+)` First capturing group. Match alphabetic characters at start of string, a colon, alphabetic characters.
- `.*$` Match anything up to the end of the string.

**Replace with** : `\1`

- `\1` Replace with captured group one.

---

You could of course make the expression more general:

**Find what** : `(^[^:]+:[^:]+).*$`

- `(^[^:]+:[^:]+)` Capturing group. Match anything other than a colon at start of string, a colon, anything other than a colon.
- `.*$` Match anything up to end of string.

**Replace with** : `\1`

- `\1` Replace with captured group one.

As pointed out by revo in the comment below, you should disable the `matches newline` option when using the patterns above in Notepad++.

Comment: It is good enough to have `^([^\r\n:]*:[^\r\n:]*).*` as the regex.

Comment: Indeed, no need for the second capturing group. I'll edit, cheers.

Comment: No need for `$` anchor and `+` quantifier too. Also considering newlines should be a workaround here otherwise it may match more than needed.

Comment: No need sure, but it's probably good practice. Good point about the newline though.

Comment: Sorry but it's probably not a good practice since OP may have nothing before and after first colon and doing `.*` makes a dollar sign useless.

Comment: Disabling *`.` matches newlines* doesn't affect `[^:]+`. `[^:]+` goes beyond one line. You have to explicitly include CRLF.

Comment: From the string OP provided, that is the case. On my version of Notepad++ that is by default, perhaps because I am running Windows.

Comment: OS doesn't matter. `[^:]+` means any thing but a colon which could be a `\r` or `\n`.

Comment: I am aware of that. I tested it on my Notepad++ and strings on newlines were not replaced.

Comment: yeah, this is literally just highlighting all of my lines, even when using "matches newline"

Comment: @Zachary Have you tried disabling `matches newline` ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you can use the plugin [ConyEdit](https://www.conyedit.com/) to do this. You can use its command `cc.dac <nth>/<regex>/[<mode>] [-options]`. `cc.dac` means: delete after column.

For Example:
With ConyEdit running in the background, copy the text and the command line below, then paste:

```
 apple:orange:banana:grapes:
 cc.dac 2/:/ -d
```

Answer (score 0):

How big is the file?

If it's a small file, you could probably write a simple code something like following snippet in java. Most the programming languages would support such operations.

```
String input = "apple:orange:banana:grapes:";
String[] arrOfStr = input.split(":");
int index = arrOfStr.indexOf("orange");
String[] arrOfStrSub = Arrays.copyOf(arrOfStr, 0, index);
String output = StringUtils.join(arrOfStrSub, ':');
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question They want a solution for notepad++.